# Bash insert a variable into a backticked command

Tags: bash, variables, backticks

I need to use this command

```
/usr/local/bin/mcl find -f .bz2
```

which returns me this

```
:???????? '/Cloud Drive/test1.bz2'
:???????? '/Cloud Drive/test2.bz2'
```

into a BASH script. The problem is that I need the last parameter (.bz2) to be a variable.

I've tried with this

```
FILENAME=".bz2"
UPLOADED=$(/usr/local/bin/mcl find -f $FILENAME)
# do something with $UPLOADED
```

But obviously it is not working. After some research on StackOverflow and on the web I have found several ways to do something like that (even using backticks), but still I can't manage to make it work.

What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: This structure works for me. If I create a BASH file containing `VARIABLE="content"` followed by `RESULT=$(echo $VARIABLE)` then `echo $RESULT` outputs simply `content`. What do you get instead of the expected result? Can you edit your question to add the error message or incorrect output?

Comment: @Arkanon, that's true for `content`. It's not true for `$'content\n\n'` -- the trailing newlines get stripped. It's not true for `"*"` unless you fix the quoting at expansion time (`echo "$VARIABLE"`, not `echo $VARIABLE`). It's not true for `-e` or `-n` if your echo eats those parameters. Etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
uploaded=$(mcl find -f "$FILENAME" | cut -d"'" -f2)
for u in $uploaded; do
    echo "$u"
    # process "$u"
done
```

Comment: This is a bit more than what I needed but it works perfectly. I was probably missing the double quotes as you stated in your other comment and and this was causing my check to fail. Thanks!!

Comment: @ToX82 Not really understand how this could work for your example, where the `mcl` returns `'/Cloud Drive/test1.bz2'` - e.g. space separated path, and the `for u in $uploaded` will assign to `u` 1st `/Cloud` and 2nd `Drive/test1.bz2`... So strange accept...

Answer (score 1):

You can try save the following as e.g. `./script.sh`

```
filename="${1:-.bz2}"    #<-- your variable as 1st argument, defaults to .bz2

do_my_work() {
    local uploaded="$1"
    #do whatever you want with the "uploaded"
    printf "got:==%s==\n" "$uploaded"
}

while IFS= read -r __mc1path
do
    do_my_work "$__mc1path"
done < <(mc1 find -f "$filename" | sed "s/.*'\(.*\)'.*/\1/")
#        variable----^^^^^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^- keep only stuff inside of quotes
```

and use it as

```
./script.sh .bz2   #or anything, defaults to ".bz2"
```

and will print

```
got:==/Cloud Drive/test1.bz2==
got:==/Cloud Drive/test2.bz2==
```

Comment: Might clear IFS during the read to avoid stripping whitespace from the end of filenames. Otherwise, this looks about perfect.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy YES! and YES! and again YES! everytimes forget it. ;) :) added... thanx. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I think you want that :

```
UPLOADED=`/usr/local/bin/mcl find -f $FILENAME`
```

Comment: Well yes, but that is the same thing I was trying with backticks instead of $()... I'd like a working version of that :)

Comment: Just a question : UPLOADED=$(/usr/local/bin/mcl find -f .bz2) gives you back the right result?

Comment: Yes, even if it is separated by a space and not a newline (which is the same for what I need)

    :???????? '/Cloud Drive/test1.bz2' :???????? '/Cloud Drive/test2.bz2'

Comment: No, it isn't. The space appears when you `echo $UPLOADED` without double quotes. The proper syntax is `echo "$UPLOADED"`.

Comment: @sotcha, storing lists of paths in scalar variables isn't exactly good practice -- since the only character that can't exist anywhere in a path is `NUL`, and scalar variables in bash (like every other shell using C-style strings) can't store NULs, such approaches are doomed to having filenames that they can't correctly handle.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I don't get your point, NUL can't exist in a path and scalar can't store NUL. Where is the problem ? Do you have any example where storing lists of paths in scalar caused problem ? Any documentation suggestion ?

Comment: @ToX82 PARAM=".jpg"; LIST=$(mcl find -f $PARAM) ; echo "$LIST"; Gives me back a list with my jpg !

Comment: @sotcha, the problem is if you want to have *more than one* path inside a single scalar. You literally can't do it without restricting the range of possible filenames more tightly than the filesystem itself does, because how are you going to separate the names? A newline is common, but inadequate: Newlines are legal inside POSIX filenames. So, how do you tell the difference between one file `$'foo\nbar'` and two files `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Got it thanx. But what's your solution about files with newline, because no solution in this page solves that problem. I tried them with filename that contains a newline.

Comment: @sotcha, that depends on the details of how the input format delimits names. The ideal case is to have the input format NUL-delimited, and use a `while IFS='' read -r -d ''` loop to pull names off the stream. Other, less-ideal solutions exist... but depends again on the input stream spec, and I have no idea how `mcl` is intended to handle the case.

Comment: ...anyhow -- using an array rather than a scalar means that _storage_ works correctly with arbitrary names, and then decouples the matter of _parsing_ to be separately handled.

Comment: (If your input format uses escape sequences like `\n` to represent newlines and special characters, then you'd actually leave the `-r` off the `read` command at parse time, and they'll be interpreted rather than stored literally).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62498/discussion-between-sotcha-and-charles-duffy).